# Changing the Second Button Image by Clicking the First Button IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, image, button

Hi I'm trying to change the button image by clicking the another button for example i have two buttons like button1 and button2 already this two button has images but now I'm trying to change the second button image by clicking the first button in second button the new image should replace the old image please tell me how to do it.

```
      - (IBAction)bt1:(id)sender {
           UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
           [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

  - (IBAction)bt2:(id)sender {

       }

   **[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"]** forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This above code is used to change the button image but i want know how to change the second button image by clicking image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you set your both button tag..l`ike btn1 tag =1 and btn2 tag =2`

```
- (IBAction)bt1:(id)sender {
           UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
           [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

  - (IBAction)bt2:(id)sender {

       }
```

Comment: pls tell how to set tag for button 2

Comment: its working but its not replacing the old image pls tell how to do it

Comment: Have you changed the image name in the [UIImage imageNamed:@"......" This should work...

Answer (score 2):

You might have the `IBAction` property of a second button, which you can access in your implementation (.m) file with `self` (e.g. `self.secondButtonPropertyName`), now you can write the code like below:

```
-(IBAction)bt1:(id)sender 
{               
   [self.btn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vv.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have two buttons btn1 and btn2

Now after them allocatng memory,
you can use below Button selector,

btn1 selector,

```
-(IBAction)btn1selector:(id)sender
{
[btn2 setbackgroundimage: [uiimage imagenamed:@"your image"]];

}
```

you can do same for the other button selector.